# How to use root privileges in my app

Tags: android, root

I'm trying to develop an app in android and I want to give the option of delete a file that is in a data, system folder which needs root privileges. How I can give access root to my app?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't until your app is a part of framework

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I have found

you must specify `android.permission.FACTORY_TEST` permission. [docs here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#FACTORY_TEST)

For accessing `root` permission you can use

```
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
```

Source : [Here](http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/01/android-requesting-root-access-in-your-app/)

Answer (score 1):

For the people how search the same.

[Root Tools Library](https://code.google.com/p/roottools/wiki/Usage)

With RootTools we can make that type of operations.

Thanks.